# failed to open stream: File name too long

Tags: php

I'm facing this error when trying to get the contents of a url:

**failed to open stream: File name too long in** ...

Code:

```
    $url = "/var/www/vhosts/myvhost/scripts/needed_script.cgi?needed_param1=some_value&needed_param2=some_value&needed_param3=some_value"; // and continues up to a long of 926 chars

    $url = str_replace(' ','%20',$url);

    $web = file_get_contents($url);

    $web = implode('', $web );
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this error? Some php.ini setting or anything..

It happens with a new server with PHP 5.3, on the old one, with PHP 4.3 didn't happen.

Comment: Why are you including a file path as a url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass query parameters to a filesystem path.